# Value row and empty row added to MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm inputting values into a MySQL database.  The values are always being inputted correctly.  However, each time a new row enters the table, two rows are being added to the database (one empty row and with a value of either 1 or 2).  Any ideas how to stop this empty row being added?  Thanks

```
<div id="post" data-value="1"></div></div>
<div id="post" data-value="2"></div></div> 



$('div').click( function(e){
console.log("a")
x= $(e)[0].currentTarget

var data = {"emotion":$(x).context.dataset["value"]}
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "insert.php",
data: data
})
});
```

insert.php

```
 $number = $_POST["number"];
 $sql = "INSERT INTO test(number) VALUES ('$number');";
```

Comment: Why are you closing the divs twice?

Comment: Do you loop over this sql?

Comment: @TheWolf they have different css styles but i didnt add them to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> in your insert.php file check condition

```
if(isset($_POST["number"]) && $_POST["number"]!=''  )
{
 $number = $_POST["number"];

 $sql = "INSERT INTO test(number) VALUES ('$number');";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div').click(...
```

... means you add a click event on any div. Try using

```
$('div#post').click(...
```